# MongoDB C# 2.0 Driver Query Where Field A is Less Than Field B

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the C# 2.0 MongoDB Driver.

I am trying to find all documents where field A is less than field B.

I tried this:

```
var filter = Builders<Stock>.Filter.Where(s => s.LastPrice < s.MosPrice);
var result = await _collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
return result;
```

But I received the following error:

> System.ArgumentException Unsupported filter: (Serialization(LastPrice)
>   < Serialization(MosPrice)).

How can I perform this query using the new C# MongoDB Driver?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this type of queries I use `BsonJavaScript`:

With **old driver**:

```
var filter = Query.Where(new BsonJavaScript("this.LastPrice < this.MosPrice"));
```

With **new driver**:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument(new BsonDocument("$where", new BsonJavaScript("this.LastPrice < this.MosPrice")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurs becouse in where condition  you try to filter by not constant value. Mongo db driver not support this case.

Comment: So what options do I have? How else could I perform this query? Is there any option at all?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you simply cannot:

"The issue with your query is that MongoDB does not allowing comparing two fields to each other. You can only compare fields to a constant. Because of this restriction, we cannot convert the query. It is simply not valid MongoDB syntax.

I'm going to close this ticket as Works as Designed."

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1592

Comment: It is indeed possible, so I don't know why this was closed. See Michal's answer.